# Curl ответ код 0

Tags: php, curl

Имеется определенный curl запрос(php ), при запросе на сайт возвращает http_code 0, через браузер этот же запрос возвращает 302. Также в браузере проскакивает этот же запрос методом OPTIONS, имеется предположение, может это как то взаимосвязано, и нужно еще посылать запрос OPTIONS? Или может дело вообще в другом?

```
function func1($param1, $param2){
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sitename.ru/file.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate, br');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
                                        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
                                        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'
                                        ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
'param1' => $param1,
'param2' => $param2
)));
$out = curl_exec($curl);
$result = json_decode($out, true);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: `if( curl_exec($curl) === false ) { var_dump( curl_error($curl) ); }` что пишет? http_code 0 значит соединение закрылось до вывода чего-либо

Comment: Ничего не пишет, ошибок нет, getifo показывает http_code 0

Comment: я бы этот запрос попробовал с консоли обычным курлом сделать. А там по результатам будет понятно.

Comment: @UserAgent122 значит ищите проблему тут `https://api.sitename.ru/file.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это работает CORS. Почитайте [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com");?>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, да действительно, имеется такой заголовок. Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты обхода/подделывание? Может это как-то связано как я и писал выше с запросом методом OPTIONS. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: В cors option запрос отправляется автоматически в браузере. Просто не всегда это заметно. Почитайте документацию

Answer (score 0):

У вас запрос идёт на HTTPs, поэтому либо выключайте проверку сертификата через

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

либо устанавливайте путь до сертификата через

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, “/var/your_path/to/cert.ca”);
```

Comment: Ну не знаю, обычно получаешь ошибку от curl, что сертификатов нет...

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендации, но увы, проблему это не решило(

Comment: Попробуйте curl_error($ch). [Код 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227879/php-curl-http-code-return-0) означает что вы не смогли подсоединиться к серверу, вам нужно смотреть в сторону curl_errno либо curl_error.

Comment: В том то и вся загвоздка, curl_error, говорит, что ошибок никаких нет

Comment: Можете связаться с их службой поддержки, если таковая имеется ;)

Comment: Имеется, но они не предоставляют открытые апи), если было бы все так легко) Но как ответили ниже, скорее всего это Cors, буду теперь думать в этом направление. Спасибо за ваши советы!